# Calculate fmax of Altera design

Tags: vhdl, fpga, state-machine, intel-fpga, quartus

After I finished my design compilation on Quartus, I get multiple result for fmax as shown below. I want to know, what does it means? and How can I calculate the fmax of the all design?.

[image]

My design is implementation for the following equation:

```
for(i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
  T += ( ((Rv[i] - Ru[i]))^2 + ((Iv[i] - Iu[i]))^2 )
}
```

assume the following:
1. use 4 add-sub, 2 squarer, and eight 21-bit register file(parallel input/output) .
2. finished all operation in 8 clock cycles.

Note: - each adder/subtractor is 21-bit and has a selector pin '1' for add or '0' for sub.
- squarer is 9 bit.
- T is 21 bit.

This is the FSM for my design 
[image]

According the above, this is my code

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;



entity EDCfunction_TopEntity is
port
    (
        clk, reset  :   in std_logic;
        Rv1 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iv1 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Ru1 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iu1 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Rv2 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iv2 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Ru2 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iu2 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Rv3 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iv3 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Ru3 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iu3 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Rv4 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iv4 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Ru4 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        Iu4 :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);

        T       :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0)

    );
end EDCfunction_TopEntity;

architecture behavioral of EDCfunction_TopEntity is
type clock_state is (zero, zero_clk2, one, two, two_clk2, three, three_clk2, four, four_clk2, five, six, seven, eight);
type add_sub_type is array (4-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
type squarer_in_type is array (2-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (9-1 downto 0);
type squarer_out_type is array (2-1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (18-1 downto 0);

signal cc_state, cn_state : clock_state;
signal clk_reg_file, reset_reg_file, s_wr_en : std_logic;
signal add_sub_flage, state_mux : std_logic_vector (4-1 downto 0);
signal dataa_add_sub, datab_add_sub, result_add_sub : add_sub_type;
signal dataa_squarer : squarer_in_type;
signal result_squarer : squarer_out_type;
signal w_addr_reg_file, r_addr_reg_file : std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
signal s_w_data_0, s_w_data_1, s_w_data_2, s_w_data_3, s_w_data_4, s_w_data_5, s_w_data_6, s_w_data_7,
            s_r_data_0, s_r_data_1, s_r_data_2, s_r_data_3, s_r_data_4, s_r_data_5, s_r_data_6, s_r_data_7 
            : std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);

alias R0 is s_w_data_0(21-1 downto 0);
alias R0H is s_w_data_0(21-1 downto 10);
alias R0L is s_w_data_0(9 downto 0);

alias R1 is s_w_data_1(21-1 downto 0);
alias R1H is s_w_data_1(21-1 downto 10);
alias R1L is s_w_data_1(9 downto 0);

alias R2 is s_w_data_2(21-1 downto 0);
alias R2H is s_w_data_2(21-1 downto 10);
alias R2L is s_w_data_2(9 downto 0);

alias R3 is s_w_data_3(21-1 downto 0);
alias R3H is s_w_data_3(21-1 downto 10);
alias R3L is s_w_data_3(9 downto 0);

alias R4 is s_w_data_4(21-1 downto 0);
alias R4H is s_w_data_4(21-1 downto 10);
alias R4L is s_w_data_4(9 downto 0);

alias R5 is s_w_data_5(21-1 downto 0);
alias R5H is s_w_data_5(21-1 downto 10);
alias R5L is s_w_data_5(9 downto 0);

alias R6 is s_w_data_6(21-1 downto 0);
alias R6H is s_w_data_6(21-1 downto 10);
alias R6L is s_w_data_6(9 downto 0);

alias R7 is s_w_data_7(21-1 downto 0);
alias R7H is s_w_data_7(21-1 downto 10);
alias R7L is s_w_data_7(9 downto 0);

component lpm_adder_subtractor
port
    (
        add_sub     : IN STD_LOGIC ;
        dataa           : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (20 DOWNTO 0);
        datab           : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (20 DOWNTO 0);
        result      : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (20 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end component;

component lpm_squarer
    PORT
    (
        dataa       : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 DOWNTO 0);
        result      : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (17 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end component;

component register_file
port
    (
        clk, reset      :   in std_logic;
        wr_en       :   in std_logic;
        w_addr  :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        w_data_0    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        w_data_1    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        w_data_2    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        w_data_3    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        w_data_4    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        w_data_5    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        w_data_6    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        w_data_7    :   in std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_addr  :   in std_logic_vector (8-1 downto 0);
        r_data_0    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_data_1    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_data_2    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_data_3    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_data_4    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_data_5    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_data_6    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0);
        r_data_7    :   out std_logic_vector (21-1 downto 0)
    );
end component;


begin
A0 : lpm_adder_subtractor port map (add_sub_flage(0), dataa_add_sub(0), datab_add_sub(0), result_add_sub(0));
A1 : lpm_adder_subtractor port map (add_sub_flage(1), dataa_add_sub(1), datab_add_sub(1), result_add_sub(1));
A2 : lpm_adder_subtractor port map (add_sub_flage(2), dataa_add_sub(2), datab_add_sub(2), result_add_sub(2));
A3 : lpm_adder_subtractor port map (add_sub_flage(3), dataa_add_sub(3), datab_add_sub(3), result_add_sub(3));

S0 : lpm_squarer port map (dataa_squarer(0), result_squarer(0));
S1 : lpm_squarer port map (dataa_squarer(1), result_squarer(1));

U0 : register_file port map (clk, reset_reg_file, s_wr_en, w_addr_reg_file, s_w_data_0, s_w_data_1, s_w_data_2,
                        s_w_data_3, s_w_data_4, s_w_data_5, s_w_data_6, s_w_data_7, r_addr_reg_file,
                        s_r_data_0, s_r_data_1, s_r_data_2, s_r_data_3, s_r_data_4, s_r_data_5, s_r_data_6,
                        s_r_data_7);

process (cc_state, reset, Rv1, Iv1, Ru1, Iu1, Rv2, Iv2, Ru2, Iu2, Rv3, Iv3, Ru3, Iu3, Rv4, Iv4, Ru4, Iu4)
begin
    case cc_state is
        when zero =>
            s_wr_en <= '1';
            w_addr_reg_file <= "11111111";
            R0H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Rv1), R0H'length));
            R0L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Ru1), R0L'length));
            R1H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iv1), R1H'length));
            R1L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iu1), R1L'length));
            R2H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Rv2), R2H'length));
            R2L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Ru2), R2L'length));
            R3H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iv2), R3H'length));
            R3L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iu2), R3L'length));
            R4H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Rv3), R4H'length));
            R4L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Ru3), R4L'length));
            R5H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iv3), R5H'length));
            R5L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iu3), R5L'length));
            R6H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Rv4), R6H'length));
            R6L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Ru4), R6L'length));
            R7H <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iv4), R7H'length));
            R7L <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(Iu4), R7L'length));

            --clk_reg_file <= '1';
            --T <= result_add_sub(0);

            cn_state <= zero_clk2;

        when zero_clk2 =>
            r_addr_reg_file <= "11111111";
            cn_state <= one;

        when one =>
            s_wr_en <= '0';
            --w_addr_reg_file <= "00001111";
            add_sub_flage(0) <= '0';
            add_sub_flage(1) <= '0';
            add_sub_flage(2) <= '0';
            add_sub_flage(3) <= '0';

            --r_addr_reg_file <= "00001111";
            dataa_add_sub(0) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_0 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(0)'length));
            datab_add_sub(0) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_0 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(0)'length));
            --s_w_data_0 <= result_add_sub(0);
            --w_addr_reg_file <= "00000001";

            dataa_add_sub(1) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_1 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(1)'length));
            datab_add_sub(1) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_1 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(1)'length));
            --s_w_data_1 <= result_add_sub(1);
            --w_addr_reg_file <= "00000010";

            dataa_add_sub(2) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_2 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(2)'length));
            datab_add_sub(2) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_2 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(2)'length));
            --s_w_data_2 <= result_add_sub(2);
            --w_addr_reg_file <= "00000100";

            dataa_add_sub(3) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_3 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(3)'length));
            datab_add_sub(3) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_3 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(3)'length));
            --s_w_data_3 <= result_add_sub(3);
            --w_addr_reg_file <= "00001000";
            --T <= result_add_sub(3);

            --clk_reg_file <= '1';
            --r_addr_reg_file <= "11110000";
            cn_state <= two;
            --state_mux <= "0001";
        when two =>
            s_wr_en <= '1';
            w_addr_reg_file <= "00001111";
            R0 <= result_add_sub(0);
            R1 <= result_add_sub(1);
            R2 <= result_add_sub(2);
            R3 <= result_add_sub(3);

            dataa_squarer(0) <= result_add_sub(0) (9-1 downto 0);
            dataa_squarer(1) <= result_add_sub(1) (9-1 downto 0);

            dataa_add_sub(0) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_4 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(0)'length));
            datab_add_sub(0) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_4 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(0)'length));

            dataa_add_sub(1) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_5 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(1)'length));
            datab_add_sub(1) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_5 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(1)'length));

            dataa_add_sub(2) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_6 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(2)'length));
            datab_add_sub(2) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_6 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(2)'length));

            dataa_add_sub(3) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_7 (21-1 downto 10)), dataa_add_sub(3)'length));
            datab_add_sub(3) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(s_r_data_7 (9 downto 0)), dataa_add_sub(3)'length));

            cn_state <= two_clk2;

        when two_clk2 =>
            cn_state <= three;
        when three =>
            --s_wr_en <= '1';
            w_addr_reg_file <= "11110011";
            R0 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), R0'length));
            R1 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), R0'length));
            R4 <= result_add_sub(0);
            R5 <= result_add_sub(1);
            R6 <= result_add_sub(2);
            R7 <= result_add_sub(3);

            add_sub_flage(0) <= '1';
            dataa_add_sub(0) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), dataa_add_sub(0)'length));
            datab_add_sub(0) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), datab_add_sub(0)'length));
            dataa_squarer(0) <= s_r_data_2 (9-1 downto 0);
            dataa_squarer(1) <= s_r_data_3 (9-1 downto 0);

            cn_state <= three_clk2;

        when three_clk2 =>
            cn_state <= four;
        when four =>
            w_addr_reg_file <= "00000110";
            R0 <= result_add_sub(0);
            R1 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), R0'length));
            R2 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), R0'length));

            add_sub_flage(1) <= '1';
            dataa_add_sub(1) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), dataa_add_sub(1)'length));
            datab_add_sub(1) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), datab_add_sub(1)'length));
            dataa_squarer(0) <= s_r_data_4 (9-1 downto 0);
            dataa_squarer(1) <= s_r_data_5 (9-1 downto 0);

            cn_state <= four_clk2;

        when four_clk2 =>
            cn_state <= five;
        when five =>
            w_addr_reg_file <= "00001110";
            R1 <= result_add_sub(1);
            R2 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), R2'length));
            R3 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), R3'length));

            add_sub_flage(2) <= '1';
            dataa_add_sub(0) <= R0;
            datab_add_sub(0) <= result_add_sub(1);
            dataa_add_sub(2) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), dataa_add_sub(2)'length));
            datab_add_sub(2) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), datab_add_sub(2)'length));
            dataa_squarer(0) <= s_r_data_6 (9-1 downto 0);
            dataa_squarer(1) <= s_r_data_7 (9-1 downto 0);

            cn_state <= six;
        when six =>
            w_addr_reg_file <= "00001111";
            R0 <= result_add_sub(0);
            R1 <= result_add_sub(2);
            R2 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), R2'length));
            R3 <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), R3'length));

            add_sub_flage(3) <= '1';
            dataa_add_sub(0) <= result_add_sub(0);
            datab_add_sub(0) <= result_add_sub(2);
            dataa_add_sub(3) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(0)), dataa_add_sub(2)'length));
            datab_add_sub(3) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(result_squarer(1)), datab_add_sub(2)'length));

            cn_state <= seven;
        when seven =>
            w_addr_reg_file <= "00000011";
            R0 <= result_add_sub(0);
            R1 <= result_add_sub(3);

            dataa_add_sub(0) <= result_add_sub(0);
            datab_add_sub(0) <= result_add_sub(3);
            --R0 <= result_add_sub(0);
            --T <= result_add_sub(0);

            cn_state <= eight;

        when eight =>
            w_addr_reg_file <= "00000001";
            R0 <= result_add_sub(0);
            T <= result_add_sub(0);

            cn_state <= zero;
        end case;

    --if(state_mux = "0001") then


    --end if;
end process;



process (clk, reset)
begin
    reset_reg_file <= reset;

    if(reset = '1') then
        cc_state <= zero;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
        cc_state <= cn_state;
    end if;
end process;

end behavioral;
```

Any help,
Regards

Comment: IMHO you would be better off with the single-process form of state machine, where "clk" is explicitly the only clock. That will avoid trouble with signals missing from the sensitivity list (I can see some here). Which may be why this code appears to be generating numeric results "clocked" by your state signals with apparently no actual pipeline registers. Also, a better choice of types (probably, Signed instead of std_logic_vector) would save a LOT of type conversions...

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Thanks a lot. I already working through changing the types, but it's better to clear for me more a bout what you mean by the first part on your comment?, and if there is some thing bad on my code.

Answer (score 2):

`cc_state` is presumably being treated as a clock in your 'combinatorial' process, but your code is too complex to make it obvious why. It's likely that you're reading something before assigning to it, which implies clocked functionality. Your synthesis report will tell you what `cc_state` is clocking, and why.

You need to rewrite your code to simplify it - this is way too complex. Move out your LPM code into a new module which is unclocked. This should be controlled by your 3-bit state signal. Instantiate this in your top-level clocked module, which should contain only the register file, and a simplified FSM.

You should also think about:

1. Move the stuff in the architecture declarative region into a package
2. Make use of subtypes to get rid of all the `std_logic_vector` stuff
3. If you end up with a `case` statement in your combinatorial module, make sure that you set default values for all outputs, or assign in all branches (your existing code doesn't assign to `s_wr_en` in all branches)

If it still doesn't work, post a much simpler question. Your algorithm isn't relevant to the question.